# Why are pointers used for std::string.find?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

Originally, I used `string_array.find(item)` to search, but the compiler said no.

Then I searched to see if we can use `string_array->find(item)` to solve the problem by using pointer, but there is no explanation.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
string name [100];
int Jan[100]={0}, Feb[100]={0}, Mar[100]={0}, Apr[100]={0}, May[100] = 0, Jun[100]={0},Jul[100]={0}, Aug[100]={0},Sep[100]={0},Oct[100]={0},Nov[100]={0},Dec[100]={0};
int earning [100];
int main () {
    ifstream load;
    load.open("record.txt");
    if(load.fail()){
        cout << "error in loading data" << endl;
        exit(1);
    } 
    else {
int i = 0;
    string NAME;
    int EARNING;
    int MONTH;
    int dump1;
    char dump2;
    while ( load.eof() != 1 ) {
        int n = 0;
        load >> NAME >> EARNING >> dump1 >> dump2 >> MONTH >> dump2 >> dump1 ;
        n = name->find(NAME);
        if ( n < 0 ) {
            n = i ;
        } 
        else {
    i = i - 1 ;
        }
        name[n] = NAME;
        if ( MONTH == 1) { Jan[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 2) { Feb[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 3) { Mar[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 5) { Apr[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 5) { May[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 6) { Jun[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 7) { Jul[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 8) { Aug[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 9) { Sep[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 10) { Oct[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 11) { Nov[n] += EARNING ;}
        if ( MONTH == 12) { Dec[n] += EARNING ;}
        i++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually no need to look into the code in great details.......just read a file from ifstream......have an array of name[100]........cin >> to give NAME, then, use ;;find to search the name[100] if NAME exists before

Comment: +1 "but the compiler said no" probably the _BEST_ thing I've ever heard regarding a compiler error. I mean, compilers are becoming more self aware regarding our code, so it saw the code and didn't want to fix it, so it just says no. Running `gcc main.c`. Output `GCC 4.8.1: No`.

Comment: Your while loop won't work like you want it to. `load.eof()` won't return true until *after* you tried to read from it and the read failed because the end of file was reached. Your loop condition should be whether the read succeeded (as in `while(load >> whatever) {...}`). Also it's bad style to give variables all-uppercase names (that's for macros) and it's really bad style to have two variables whose name is the same except for case.

Comment: while i used while( load>> wtever ){ ....} , the function name->find(NAME) no longer function as before....so, i have two question.....(1) why can it function if used as above ( neglect the failure of eof ) ??..........(2) why can it function when i turn to while ( load >> wtever){..........} ??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it compiles is a coincidence - it just calls find on the first string from the array. I suppose you wanted to find the string within the array, so you should be using something like [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/):

```
string *begin = name;
string *end = begin + 100;

if (end == std::find(begin, end, NAME))
{
  // not found
}
```

But it would be probably better to switch to `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: so do u mean that the name[100] is changed to a pointer calling the first string and doing sth like a link list ??
thxxx for the comment.....im just a beginner of coding  and sorry for asking such a idiot question......

Comment: In C++ the name of the table is also a pointer to it's first element. So nothing is changed, you just accidentally accessed the first element using this feature of the language.

Answer (score 5):

`name` is an array of 100 strings.  If you use an array name by itself like you are, it decays into a pointer to its first element.  Your code:

```
n = name->find(NAME);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
n = (&name[0])->find(NAME);
```

So you can see how that value is a pointer and needs to be operated on with `->` rather than `.`.  If it helps, `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`.

I think your code is buggy though;  are you really sure that's how you want it to work?

Comment: is it like that . we call an array and use & to make it pass by reference as modifiable  ............ and how does * mean to be a pointer and where is the address for pointer  ??? ......btw, thxxxx for the comment

Answer (score 5):

The fact with this line:

```
n = name->find(NAME);
```

is that it is not doing what you think. Here you are using the [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) method on a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). The first element of the array. Not the array itself. In addition, this line of code is no different than:

```
n = (*name).find(NAME);
```

So, your code is searching if `NAME` is present in the first element of your string array. To search an entire array, I would suggest you use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It gives you access to the standard [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) methods:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> name(100);
// ...
it = find(name.begin(), name.end(), NAME);
// std::find return an iterator
if (it == name.end())
    // NOT FOUND
else
    // FOUND
```

Comment: A minor thing: ordinary array also can be used with std::find. So it's not true that vector _gives_ access to iterator methods (suggests that array doesn't).